# Fix div position with a responsive width after scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

My goal is to show a div as position fixed after certain scrolling and display the div element with a responsive width.

In the example below the script works, but I would like to have the same width (responsive) as the orange elements.

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index': 10000;  
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/web_garaux/y5fo1emc/28/)

Comment: If you fix the typo in your CSS (the extraneous `'`) then the code seems to do what you need

Comment: here: `z-index': 10000;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a CSS solution for the responsive width. RahulB's answer works but only using a fixed width. Here's a responsive JS solution, adding a function on window resize:

```
function resizeFixed() {
    var orWidth = $('.wrapper .group .span_4_of_4').width();
    $('.fixed').css('width', orWidth);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Treeindev/4k93t136/1/

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the help. Treeindev solution solved my responsive issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fix the typo at z-index and increase the width to 420px;

```
.fixed {
  position:fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 10000;
  width: 420px;
 }
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/y5fo1emc/33/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<section id="mainContainer">

<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_4_of_4">
 <img src="http://placehold.it/500x150">  


  </div>

  <div class="box-inner">
  <div class="section group wrapper">
    <div class="col span_4_of_4 box">
 <h1>
 I will be fixed after scrolling
 </h1>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

  </div>


<div class="section group">
    <div class="col span_4_of_4">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </section>



    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('.box-inner').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
           $('.box-inner').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
});
```

live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/y5fo1emc/37/